# JCEF ICU Check Failed

Tags: java, scala, chromium-embedded

I seem to be continually coming against a wall in getting chromium running with JCEF in eclipse. I was able to get to the point where the native functions are discovered but am still unable to complete initialization. I set the LD_PRELOAD variable. I am running both the MainFrame.java class and custom Scala code and run into the same problem in each. Is there a way to resolve this?

**System:**

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- JCEF version 3
- CEF version 3
- Java Jdk 8

**Structure and Configuration:**

Everything is under the binary distribution structure. I imported the jars as a library, added the native library path to the jcef jar and imported it into my project.

I setup the run configuration with the environment variables:

- Display = :0.0
- LD_PRELOAD = /path/to/libcef.so

All of my libraries and *.pak files are in the same directory and a subdirectory where the libcef.so is located (the binary distribution) as are the chrome sandbox and helpers.

**Code and Error**

The code fails after the following:

```
  println("Generating Handlers")
  CefApp.addAppHandler(Handlers.getHandlerAdapter)
  private var settings = new CefSettings
  settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = useOSR
  println("Starting App")
  private final val cefApp : CefApp = if(commandLineArgs != null && commandLineArgs.size > 0) CefApp.getInstance(ChromeCommandLineParser.parse(commandLineArgs)) else CefApp.getInstance(settings)
  println("Creating Client")
  private final val client : CefClient = cefApp.createClient()
```

The following output results:

```
Starting
Generating Handlers
Starting App
Creating Client
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path /home/XXXXX/jcef/src/binary_distrib/linux64/bin/lib/linux64
[0413/135633:ERROR:icu_util.cc(157)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
[0413/135633:FATAL:content_main_runner.cc(700)] Check failed: base::i18n::InitializeICU(). 
#0 0x7ff8fa94a62e base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7ff8fa95f88b logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x7ff8fd7588d4 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#3 0x7ff8fa857962 CefContext::Initialize()
#4 0x7ff8fa85775b CefInitialize()
#5 0x7ff8fa80a9b8 cef_initialize
#6 0x7ff8d6946914 CefInitialize()
#7 0x7ff8d690200f Java_org_cef_CefApp_N_1Initialize
#8 0x7ff8de207994 <unknown>
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a lot of problems with this too, until I created the symlinks to `"icudtl.dat"`, `"natives_blob.bin"` and `"snapshot_blob.bin"` under the `$jdk/bin directory`, instead of `$jdk/jre/bin`.

Now I don't get this error any more.

Using the example in https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding

I changed this...

```
$ sudo ln -s /path/to/java-cef/src/third_party/cef/linux64/Resources/icudtl.dat /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/icudtl.dat

$ sudo ln -s /path/to/java-cef/src/third_party/cef/linux64/Debug/natives_blob.bin /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/natives_blob.bin

$ sudo ln -s /path/to/java-cef/src/third_party/cef/linux64/Debug/snapshot_blob.bin /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/snapshot_blob.bin
```

To this...

```
$ sudo ln -s /path/to/java-cef/src/third_party/cef/linux64/Resources/icudtl.dat /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/icudtl.dat

$ sudo ln -s /path/to/java-cef/src/third_party/cef/linux64/Debug/natives_blob.bin /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/natives_blob.bin

$ sudo ln -s /path/to/java-cef/src/third_party/cef/linux64/Debug/snapshot_blob.bin /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/snapshot_blob.bin
```

Comment: sorry about that. took a while

Answer (score 2):

The solution that @[dvlcube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1360042/dvlcube) gave works, but it's not comfortable. You can add some extra logic to detect user's environment and if it's a linux you can copy required files - example:

- [GitHub - PandomiumLoadWorker [:53]](https://github.com/Panda-Programming-Language/Pandomium/blob/d4cf001461a0891414727f097448a400d6ed8ce0/pandomium/src/main/java/org/panda_lang/pandomium/loader/PandomiumLoaderWorker.java#L53)

Instead of copying you can also create symlinks:

- [Java SE Tutorial: Links](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html)

If you don't want to specify related to linux environment variables before launching, you can also inject those variables (like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD`) at runtime:

- [GitHub - LinuxEnv](https://github.com/dzikoysk/LinuxEnv)