# javafx embedded webbrowser for html5

Tags: html, javafx, browser, gpu

I want to embed a webbrowser in two stages of my javafx program. Using javafx webview does not work for the intended content (360° view generated with Panotour). So I have to search for alternatives.

I failed using JCEF; it does not work with javafx (neither with using SwingNode and GLJPanel).

JxBrowser looks promising, but is very expensive and closed source.

Can someone recommend a opensource(I have to extend the webbrowser)and html5 browser to embed in a javafx view? Nice to have with gpu rendering.

Thanks and greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it works only with AWT/Swing because it's too complicated to embed it in [SwingNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).

You'd have to change the structure of your application if you want to use [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef).
It's not as hard as you think, and remember - you can also embed JavaFX components in Swing using [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html). The project is still developing and trying to be more friendly, you can even found maven builds and forks:

- [GitHub: Pandomium](https://github.com/Panda-Programming-Language/Pandomium) - fork with maven builds and natives
- [Maven: JavaCef](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.johness/java-cef) - clean maven builds

Currently, you won't find a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> JxBrowser looks promising, but is very expensive and closed source.

If you your application is an open-source project, you can obtain the JxBrowser Open-Source license [here](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser#licensing-pricing).

Comment: It is also, however, a very crashy library, and the developers leave crash bugs unresolved for years.

Comment: @Hakanai if you are a customer of the library, I suppose the developers will do their best to try to solve your issue

Comment: Imagine if that were the case.